# Leading 0 in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I've been scratching my head for couple of hours and even after trying to find a solution on SO and elsewhere, I just can't seem to find the way to drop the '0' in the pandas dataframe or set index to my first item in array that I create from a array. Basically I'm trying to convert this into pandas and use it to insert into mysql db.

array

```
[u'Thu Mar 16 11:52:48 +0000 2017', u'Best Women Nice Shorts &amp; Shirt Free Shipping Xintown Road Bike Travel Clothes', 0, 0]
```

Code to convert this array to pandas df

```
df = pd.DataFrame(tweet)
print (df)
df.to_sql(con=connection, name=table_name, if_exists='append', flavor='mysql')
```

Output:

```
                                                0
1  Best Women Nice Shorts &amp; Shirt Free Shippi...
2                                                  0
3                                                  0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need create [`Series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html), because `DataFrame` has always column name, default first column is `0`:

```
s = pd.Series(tweet)
print (s)
1    Best Women Nice Shorts &amp; Shirt Free Shippi...
2                                                    0
3                                                    0
dtype: object
```

Comment: Can I use the series to upload data to sql ?

Comment: Yes, use [`Series.to_sql`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_sql.html)

Comment: Thank you for your help, much appreciated. Guess I've loads to learn. I haven't tried Series.tosql but I will accept your answer.  (PS: Cannot accept answer in 5 mins - SO just prompted, but I will do after that time)

Comment: may I ask what is the best way to store the complete Tweet JSON into one column of mysql table?

Comment: Glad can help you! Good luck! To your question - I dont know mysql, so I cannot help you, unfortunately :(